# Movie about two cops investigating and fighting with green-blooded, zombie-like people with superpowers

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

I'm looking for a movie, probably from '80s or '90s. I watched it probably in the late 90's. Almost definitely USA production. Genre was action/horror + maybe a little bit of comedy.

Key features:

- Two male protagonists (probably **cops**).
- Enemies: people infected with some kind of disease which turned them SLOWLY into green-blood zombies.
- One of the protagonists was infected and during the film and slowly changed into a zombie (without any visual changes in his appearance). During the whole film, he was behaving like a normal human, but his blood started to turn green.
- There was one particular scene I remember:
  **One of the protagonists came into a butcher shop. The butcher was a Chinese man, and there was a lot of knives and saws hanging on the walls. After some talking, butcher started using his telekinetic powers to move all his hanging knives, they started to levitate and fly through the air, and then attacked the protagonist.**
- I remember that the film ends with a funny scene where the infected protagonist is still not healed from the infection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Might this be ***[Dead Heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Heat_(1988_film))*** (1988)...?

> ***Dead Heat*** (released in the Philippines as ***Iron Cops***) is a 1988 American buddy cop action zombie comedy film directed by Mark Goldblatt and starring Treat Williams and Joe Piscopo. The film is about an LAPD police officer who is murdered while attempting to arrest zombies who have been reanimated by the head of Dante Laboratories in order to carry out violent armed robberies, and decides to get revenge with the help of his former partner.

As noted on the Wikipedia page, it is a buddy cop action comedy movie with zombies, where one of the cops becomes a zombie himself.

The cop played by Treat Williams actually dies, as a result of being sealed within an "asphyxiation room" in the first half of the film, and is resurrected using a machine which sends electricity through his body, a bit like Frankenstein's monster. He retains his normal personality and intelligence throughout the film, and looks normal for most of it, although he appears to be decomposing toward the end.

[About 39 minutes into the runtime](https://youtu.be/XF45r0o0L1g?t=2358), the two cops visit a Chinese restaurant, and speak to a large chef who was chopping up a chicken with a meat cleaver when they arrived. Then the owner walks in from another room, and after a brief conversation, he suddenly activates a machine which causes all the dead animals in the restaurant (pigs, chickens, etc) to come to life and start attacking the cops.

Comment: Amazing! You made my day. One of my life's riddles is now solved. Thank you!

How did you find it? What was your methodology?

Comment: Took me a while to find it. I tried various search terms on Google without success. I eventually found it by looking through a list of films on IMDB using the keyword "zombie," and filtering the results to show only feature films released between 1980 and 1999.

Comment: My approach to find this was much cruder -- I saw the movie and remembered it. SciFi conventions often have this as a live game. It amazes me that people also enjoy looking these up, knowing full well they've never seen or read it.

Comment: @Owen Reynolds - For me, discovering new sci-fi/fantasy material I wasn't previously familiar with is one of the main benefits of using this site. Story ID questions wouldn't be nearly as interesting if people only asked about stuff I'd already seen/read.